# Hyperref: change the font of all links, including the footnotes

Tags: hyperref

I would like to change the font of all the links produced by `hyperref`, e.g. to `sffamily`. To this end, I used the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\Hy@colorlink` command as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@colorlink}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\sffamily}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

This works for all types of links, except for footnotes. I have no idea why this is the case. A minimal working example is included below for your convenience.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% This throws an error
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%    \makeatletter
%    \patchcmd{\Hy@colorlink}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\sffamily}{}{}%
%    \makeatother
%}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@colorlink}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\sffamily}{}{}%
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{sec:toto}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Pageref: page~\pageref{sec:toto}.
    \item All links have the new font except footnotes: One\footnote{One} two\footnote{Two} three.\footnote{Three}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard command to create footnote marks contains a \normalfont command. If you remove it, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
 \AtBeginDocument{%
    \patchcmd{\Hy@colorlink}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\sffamily}{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\normalfont}{\selectfont}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{sec:toto}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Pageref: page~\pageref{sec:toto}.
    \item All links have the new font except footnotes: One\footnote{One} two\footnote{Two} three.\footnote{Three}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!